# Spark SQL - Update DataFrame Rows/Column values without converting as RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

How do i update `Spark SQL` `DataFrame` Rows/Columns values without converting as `RDD`?

Why we cannot directly update the DataFrame like `RDD` and returns another one.

Answer (score 0):

RDDs are immutable and a 'transformation' on an RDD can only generates a new RDD. Dataframes are wrappers around RDD and as such suffer from said immutablility 
for ex:

```
oldDF.registerTempTable("whatever") 

val newDF = sqlContext.sql("select field1,field2,sum(field3) as times from whatever where substring(field1,1,4)='test' group by field1,field2 having times>100").collect().saveAsParquetFile("xxx.parquet")
```

Comment: Thanks, but we need to convert DataFrame to RDD and then again RDD to DataFrame. In this scenario is there any advantage of using DataFrame for performance reasons, since we are doing lot of conversions.

Comment: The reason i want to use DataFrame is to write the content as Parquet file easily.

Comment: no need to convert to RDD. its made 'under-the-hood'. just transform the df to a new one - the underlying RDD will transform too

Comment: you can operate on the dataframe (making new ones by transformations) and then saveas Parquet

Comment: ex:
`oldDF.registerTempTable("whatever")` 




`val newDF = sqlContext.sql("select field1,field2,sum(field3) as times from whatever where substring(field1,1,4)='test' group by field1,field2 having times>100").collect().saveAsParquetFile("xxx.parquet")`

Comment: I want to apply transformation on each and every field in the DataFrame and create a new DataFrame like how we used to do it using `map()` method in `RDD`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107018/discussion-between-zahiro-mor-and-ramesh).